# Scale a website on very small viewport (<320px)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, viewport

im trying to finish a project and i cannot figure out how to scale my website for screen <320px (even if those are rare).

I like the solution from apple where the website sort of freeze and just scale down but while maintaning its orignal form. Any idea on how to reproduce this effect ? can't seem to find a easy solution for now.
(to see what im talking about: apple.com > inspect to see their size "MobileS" for screen under 320px)

Thanks

Comment: Using media query and the em for the font size you can simply modify it at every step you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using units that are related to the width and height of the screen such as vh and vw. (You can also use em for font).

Just look into vh, vw, and em as well as the max-width/height css property.